# dont get why my query is returning a null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My problem is related to when I want to Delete a Item off a Order,

I just dont get why it is returning a null value it should just delete the item.

```
protected void gvRevOrder_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Int64 ID = new Int64();
    ID = (Int64)e.Keys["ProductID"];

    using (DatabaseCourseWorkEntities  context = new DatabaseCourseWorkEntities())
    {
        CWInvoiceItem item = (from p in context.CWInvoiceItems 
                              where p.ProductID == ID 
                              select p).SingleOrDefault();

        context.CWInvoiceItems.DeleteObject(item);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

below i have put a link of the thing i am trying to delete and as you can see the ProductID = 38 and the Variable ID also has 38 any ideas?

[image]

I've tried all sorts such as FirsOrDefault and such.

Comment: Obviously, there is no `CWInvoiceItem` with that product id...

Comment: your query returns null in your item variable? Is it possible that the Product with that ID does not even exist?

Comment: And by the way, should ALWAYS expect null from any call, so make sure to trat that situation, too

Comment: it does, i have made sure of this before i posted this is why i am confused.

Comment: it does, i have made sure of this before i posted this is why i am confused.below i have put a link of the thing i am trying to delete and as you can see the ProductID = 38 and the Variable ID also has 38 any ideas?

[link](http://img713.imageshack.us/i/codeob.jpg/)

Comment: Your DataContext must be connected to a different data source than the one your image shows.

Comment: Andrew, why do you use 'Int64 ID = new Int64();' instead of 'long ID;'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that `context.CWInvoiceItems` contains ANY data
2. Check that the context points to the correct data source

Comment: thanks for your help, i appreciate it. p.s sorry About the double post and such. ive still no sorted it out but you heled me narrow it down and thanks! :)

Comment: it wont allow me to vote up untill i have 15 rep i will do so when i have this :)